# Migrating Existing Access Database to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365, ms-access-2013

I have an existing Access database.  This has grown in importance within the company and now others need access for data entry and running existing reports and queries.

I have a site on Office 365: E3. I have attempted to use the "Move Data" to "SharePoint", but this creates errors and queries do not function.

Uncertain how to proceed.  I am relatively new to Access and extremely new to SharePoint.

Comment: You need to provide some details - like exactly what errors do you get? What queries do not function? You may also want to try reproducing the problem with an Access database that is simpler than your real one.